# Как перевести бота в статус "Не в сети" с помощью команды?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при такой команде `!офлайн` у него ставился статус "Не в сети", но чтобы бот продолжал работать. Тоже самое с `!онлайн`, `!неактивен`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте написать команду

```
await bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.invisible)
```

`invisible` (это и есть статус) можно заменить на `idle` (режим "простоя")

Также в функцию можно добавить аргумент `activity`, например:

```
await bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game(name='Minecraft'))
```

После её запуска в статусе бота будет написано

**Неактивен**

**Играет в Minecraft**

Вот ваша команда:

```
@bot.command()
async def оффлайн(ctx):
    await bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.invisible)   

@bot.command()
async def онлайн(ctx):
    await bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.online)   
@bot.command()
async def играет(ctx, arg):
    await bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.invisible, activity=discord.Game(name=arg)))
```

Чтобы сделать "Играет", нужно ввести `играет` и название игры. Например: `играет Minecraft`

Comment: Когда я пишу `!играет <во что играет>`, он просто переходит в оффлайн режим...

Comment: нет, справа на панели должно появиться во что он играет. К тому же это не главное. вы же спросили про оффлайн-режим. помог ответ? поставьте галочку ;)